Mdxscript(Model) (264,25) calculatiuon error in measure of type text with the values of type number
I am writing a DAX which is throwing above error .Both my columns are in decimal format and nothing complicated in it
please help me in this
i tried changing column format to whole number but it didn't worked.

Mdxscript(Model) (264,25) calculatiuon error in measure 'xyz'[outflow]:Function 'CONTAINSROW' doesnot support comparing values of type text with the values of type number.consider using the value or Format function to convert one of the values.


Can you share some data ? your DAX code ?
